# PHP script to loop through all the folders in a zip and create an XML of that structure

Tags: php, xml, loops, zip

I need to create an XML file based on an input .zip file. The zip file will have several folders inside it including nested ones. How can I create the XML here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot expect anyone to provide you such a feature! If someone does, lucky you. Anyways, go google the stuff yourself and come back with a problem you have giving us a code sample.

Comment: This is no platform to get your code written for free. Its about helping people having trouble using something.